# How to access and nullify forced inline height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm making a website using Bootstrap 4. The opening section of the page was designed to take up 100% width and height of the screen, a hero image. Here is the code that I used to make that happen in Bootstrap.

The HTML for the element in question is

```
<section class="intro">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Large image set to display in the center of the page before scrolling down to second section.-->
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <img class="center-block col-lg-8" src="images/logotype-large.png" alt="Hatch Creative design and development agency"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

The SCSS targeting the HTML is

```
.intro{
    display: flex;
.container-fluid{
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    padding-top: 10%;
     background: #fcb037; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fcb037, #f497a0);
}
.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 15%;

 }
}
```

Javascript is using Scrollify, set to use it's most basic function, targeting sections in the body. That code is below - -`

```
$(function() {
    $.scrollify( {
        section :"section",
    });
    });
```

`
To link Scrollify, I downloaded the files and they are in the site folder. I couldn't find Scrollify's CDN online.

The problem that occurs is that when resizing the site for phones and tablets, it sets a fixed height that is entirely too large. This last image shows what I mean. 
[Image here shows that when in google dev tools, it shows that the section tag is being forced to an inline height of 896px. Nowhere in my code am I indicating that sections be a fixed pixel height, so this must be part of Bootstrap's responsive code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J05z5.png)

The issue is I can't find where I can access this feature and disable it. To my knowledge, none of my custom code should be affecting section height. Originally I had the section set to a viewport height of 100vh but I have deactivated that code for this reason. What's happening here?

Comment: Do you have any javascript?

Comment: Minimal, but I am using scrollify. Allow me to edit my entry.

Comment: [CodePen for forking/testing](https://codepen.io/mblase75/pen/pWwraY/)

Comment: Based on your code, scrollify will set the min height of each `section` to be the height of the screen. check out https://github.com/lukehaas/Scrollify/issues/31

Comment: Beautiful! So by deactivating scrollify, this will potentially solve it.

Comment: You can add `.intro {
    height: auto !important;
}` to your stylesheet to override the inline styles, but I'm not clear if that's what you want to do (or how that will affect scrollify).

Comment: Thank you both so much! Joe that solved my issue, so I suppose once mobile sizes are reached, I'll write a script that'll deactivate scrollify. Is there a way I can properly set this question to answered? I've lurked Stack Overflow for awhile now but I'm new to adding / editing content.